# Unable to generate multiple PDFs using mPDF when I do not want to download files on server

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am generating multiple PDFs in a loop using `mPDF`. Following are the lines of my code:

```
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('My html');
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

    $pdfname="Invoice_No.$i".".pdf";
    $mpdf->Output($pdfname, "I");
}
```

When the change the parameter `I` to `F` multiple PDFs are generated on the server. However when using `I` as the parameter only first PDF is generated. Is there any way that I can generate multiple PDFs in such a way that I do not have to save them in the server?

Note: Even using parameter `D` does not help either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR No, in one request, there is not.

`I` and `D` output modes generate the file, send the output from the server to the browser (inline and with forced download respectively) and end execution - so that no further data are sent that would corrupt sent PDF file.

You would have to execute multiple HTTP requests for each file.

Alternatively, you could save PDFs in-memory, later pack them eg to a ZIP file and send the ZIP file.